# Which is the best way to rename a signal in Simulink?

Tags: simulink

I am trying to rename a signal in a way that minimizes computational cost.

Let's say I have an input called ***statusA***. Then I have a bus creator with format specified by the definition of ***busDef*** that includes a signal called ***status***.

It is not possible to change the signal names of ***statusA*** and ***busDef*** because of architectural constraints.

For safety reasons I enforce strong data typing when creating ***busDef***. When I connect the signal to the bus creator, this results in an error/warning saying that ***statusA*** does not match the bus definition, which is status.

For now I solve this with a Convert block that takes ***statusA*** as input and then I rename the output to status. This way the signal name that arrives to ***busDef*** is always status so there are no complaints.

I was wondering if there is a more optimal solution than having to use a convert block.

Comment: I use selector blocks to duplicate and rename signals. It might be slightly more computationally efficient since it doesn't perform a type conversion along with the signal copy.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way that I have used for this same task is to put Goto/From blocks inline with the signal who's name you want to change. You can rename the signal that is coming out of the From block to the desired new name, without any computational overhead. This will satisfy the check for name consistency in the bus creator block.